# Getting error message while using Generic in typescript

Tags: typescript, generics

I got error messages with the code below in the playground of typescript.

[image]

```
function fn<T, M = T[]>( x: T ): M {
    return [ x ];
}
```

How can I fix this and am I using the Generic in a wrong way?

I am so sorry about the simple code, and the real situation I encountered is like this:

```
type M<T> = { [key: string]: T };


function create<T>(names: string[], value: T): M<T> {
    return names.reduce((a: M<T>, c: string): M<T> => (a[c] = value, a), {} );
}
```

I want to change the code to:

```
function create<T, M = { [key: string]: T }>(names: string[], value: T): M {
    return names.reduce((a: M, c: string): M => (a[c] = value, a), {} );
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAigJwKYEMYYDwAqANMgLLIC8yA3sgNoDWGAngFzIDOMacEA5gF12BZAF8AfAAoIWALYYO7Lj350BJAG5YANmAzCAlO3LVgyc8kwwwaFDPkcAdJgAmYKBkmSsxklCXcvHxGZJTiyJLIWHSoyAKUyFq6GCRYyAYk1KIGANzAosBAA)

Comment: Why do you need the second type parameter? Just `function fn<T>( x: T ) { return [ x ]; }`

Comment: The real code is more complex, I just made a simple example and ran it in the playground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need the second type parameter:

```
function create<T>(names: string[], value: T): Record<string, T> {
    return names.reduce((a, c) => (a[c] = value, a), {} as Record<string, T>);
}
```

** `Record<string, T>` is just an [alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt) to `{ [key: string]: T }`

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBATgUwIZTQHgCoB8AFGBgLZoDOAXIpVCjGAOYDaAugDSIBuGANiDS08ASloAlNBDgoAJjnqMW3QogDeAKEQ7E6KCBRJSFSgDp0ckBDREiGbhFGIAvAUT3WEdq94Ch3Bii3OoAvogYlIhSMvKKDEzMqgSiANyaoUA)